# Whether visual tranform can be implemented in windows machine?

Tags: transforms, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My requirement is that, I need to run a tf listener in windows machine. either through Python script or cpp code.

I was able to run ,Simple Publisher and Subscriber (Python) on a Windows machine, successfully,

Also, I tried the following http://servicerobotics.eu/en/other-projects/ros-fuer-windows/

Please advise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252367/whether-visual-tranform-can-be-implemented-in-windows-machine-?/) by [Parvathy](https://answers.ros.org/users/29108/parvathy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Parvathy,

It is currently not possible to run ROS from Windows. There has been some experimentation with the [Ubuntu Bash on Windows 10](http://answers.ros.org/question/238646/installing-ros-on-ubuntu-bash-in-windows-10/), but as you can read that is by no means fully functional. Another thing you could try is [rosserial_windows](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows), I haven't used it so don't know how/if it works, but perhaps that's worth a try.

If at all possible, running ROS on a supported platform is a much better option.

Good luck.

PS: I have closed your other question, as it was a duplicate of this one.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Parvathy](https://answers.ros.org/users/29108/parvathy/) on 2017-01-20**:
My requirement is that, I need to run a tf listener in windows machine. either through Python script or cpp code.

I was able to run ,Simple Publisher and Subscriber (Python) on a Windows machine, successfully,

Also, I tried the following http://servicerobotics.eu/en/other-pr...

Please advise.

**Comment by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) on 2017-01-20**:
Did you mean on a Linux Machine? Like I said, it is currently not possible, bar some very experimental approaches that might not be able to do what you want even with a lot of work.

**Comment by [Parvathy](https://answers.ros.org/users/29108/parvathy/) on 2017-01-20**:
Not on Linux Machine .

I am trying on windows 7 machine.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-20**:
@Parvathy: you could see whether [codenotes/ros_cygwin](https://github.com/codenotes/ros_cygwin) is performant enough. Or [uml-robotics/ROS.NET](https://github.com/uml-robotics/ROS.NET), `rosjava` or any of the Javascript based approaches. Or `rosbridge_suite`.